# Print lines where every word of the line with capital letters starts with a different letter

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have this text:

```
FOUR MILLION, EIGHT HUNDRED AND FIFTY-SEVEN THOUSAND, FIVE HUNDRED AND THIRTEEN innovating
FORTY-NINE MILLION, ONE HUNDRED AND EIGHTY THOUSAND, TWO HUNDRED AND FORTY-EIGHT championed
FORTY-SEVEN MILLION, NINE HUNDRED AND FIFTY-TWO THOUSAND, EIGHT HUNDRED AND SIX swashbuckling
NINE HUNDRED AND SIXTY-ONE THOUSAND, SIX HUNDRED AND THIRTY-ONE sprinklers
FORTY-TWO MILLION, TWO HUNDRED AND SIXTY-SIX THOUSAND, THREE HUNDRED AND SEVENTY-TWO furloughs
SEVEN MILLION, FOUR HUNDRED AND SEVENTEEN THOUSAND, FOUR HUNDRED AND FORTY-TWO panicky
THREE HUNDRED AND SEVENTY-NINE THOUSAND, FIVE HUNDRED AND TWENTY-EIGHT anchovies
FIVE MILLION, EIGHT HUNDRED AND FIFTY-NINE THOUSAND, FOUR HUNDRED AND SIXTY-FOUR excesses

 ............
```

How to use `grep` or `sed` to print the lines where every word of the line with capital letters starts with a different letter?

For example:

```
FIFTY THOUSAND, NINE HUNDRED AND EIGHTEEN
FOURTEEN THOUSAND, SEVEN HUNDRED AND NINETY-EIGH
```

Comment: Welcome, please avoid writing in uppercase unless it's *absolutely* necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex to do the scanning
of the input and get the desired output.

We are telling `grep` to look for an uppercased word whose first character is found  down the line but only at beginning of another uppercased word. Since this implies at least one such match but we want no such matches is we  invert `-v` the sense of the match to get the desired output.

Edited: based on the observations by @they it is modified to look for uppercase words.

```
grep -v  '\<\([A-Z]\)[A-Z]\{1,\}\>.*\<\1[A-Z]\{1,\}\>'  file
```

Comment: Could you extend that to only compare the initial letters of words that are all caps? It's unclear in the question if that is wanted or not.

Comment: @they thanks for pointing the error. I have fixed the issue now (hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

The first task when solving a problem like this is to pick the correct tool for the job.  In this problem, we need to count the number of times each word's initial letter occurs in a line.  Both `grep` and `sed` are famously bad at counting, at least by themselves, while `awk` is more of a general-purpose programming language.  If we want to use any single tool to solve the task, `awk` would likely be better suited.

```bsh
awk '{
    delete count
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        ch = substr($i,1,1)
        if (ch == toupper(ch) && count[ch]++)
            next
    }
    print
}' file
```

The code counts the occurrences of the initial upper-case letters of all words on each line (a word being a substring delimited by whitespace). We keep the counts in the associative array `count`, indexed by the letters from the data.

We discard the line as soon we come across one of the initial letters for the second time.  We print each line that we don't discard in this way.

This code only cares if the word's *first* character is upper-case. To test the first character of words that are all upper case use the following instead:

```bsh
awk '{
    delete count
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i != toupper($i) && count[substr($i,1,1)]++)
            next
    print
}' file
```

The next issue is to understand the code. You've *got* the code now, and it works, but you might not know why.  More crucially, you may not know how to modify it to do something slightly different or how to correct it if it suddenly fails on some edge case that you discover.

You could get to know the code better by looking up each bit in the `awk` manual as a start.  Then, when you don't understand why I wrote `delete count` in that particular place and not someplace else, you could ask another question about that, or better yet, experiment with the code and note in what specific ways it breaks.

Comment: I'm still a beginner, these questions I'm solving myself for practice, in the question the word NINETY-EIGH is two words separated by  - and not one word, the command calculates it as one word

Comment: @DOSHASAN Yes, it would do, and this is why I was careful to point out what a word was.  If you want also treat `-` as a word-dividing character, use `-F [ -]` on the command line: `awk -F '[ -]' '{ ... }' file`  This would treat spaces and dashes as word-dividers.

Comment: awk: not an option: -]  I also tried this format -F [ -] or [ '-'] or ' -' or  ( -)

Comment: i have another question , awk -F , can have more than one separator ?

Comment: @DOSHASAN you do know that there is reference documentation on your machine? See `man awk` and look for the place where it describes `-F` . Follow the "see also" references and you'll find out what the parameter can accept

Comment: I did a search already, I think we can use multiple delimiters, but the problem is that here the delimiters are a space and - 
 how we can fix it !?

Comment: @DOSHASAN There was a typo in my previous comment, apologies. The `-F` option takes a string as its argument.  The string is a regular expression describing the delimiters.  The regular expression `[ -]` means "any single space or dash". That expression must be quoted on the command line, so `-F '[ -]'`.  The second example in my comment had this correctly typed out though.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .words.map(*.comb(/ ^<upper> /)).Bag.values.max == 1;'
```

Sample Input:

```
FOUR MILLION, EIGHT HUNDRED AND FIFTY-SEVEN THOUSAND, FIVE HUNDRED AND THIRTEEN innovating
FORTY-NINE MILLION, ONE HUNDRED AND EIGHTY THOUSAND, TWO HUNDRED AND FORTY-EIGHT championed
FORTY-SEVEN MILLION, NINE HUNDRED AND FIFTY-TWO THOUSAND, EIGHT HUNDRED AND SIX swashbuckling
NINE HUNDRED AND SIXTY-ONE THOUSAND, SIX HUNDRED AND THIRTY-ONE sprinklers
FORTY-TWO MILLION, TWO HUNDRED AND SIXTY-SIX THOUSAND, THREE HUNDRED AND SEVENTY-TWO furloughs
SEVEN MILLION, FOUR HUNDRED AND SEVENTEEN THOUSAND, FOUR HUNDRED AND FORTY-TWO panicky
THREE HUNDRED AND SEVENTY-NINE THOUSAND, FIVE HUNDRED AND TWENTY-EIGHT anchovies
FIVE MILLION, EIGHT HUNDRED AND FIFTY-NINE THOUSAND, FOUR HUNDRED AND SIXTY-FOUR excesses
FIFTY THOUSAND, NINE HUNDRED AND EIGHTEEN
FOURTEEN THOUSAND, SEVEN HUNDRED AND NINETY-EIGH
```

Sample Output:

```
FIFTY THOUSAND, NINE HUNDRED AND EIGHTEEN
FOURTEEN THOUSAND, SEVEN HUNDRED AND NINETY-EIGH
```

This problem is solved easily using a one-liner in Raku, the new name for the programming language formerly known as Perl6 (renamed in 2019).

Briefly, input is read linewise into Raku using the `-ne` command line flags. Input is broken into whitespace-separated `words`, each of those words is examined (using `map`) and filtered (using `comb`) for words beginning with an uppercase letter (using `^<upper>` regex). Those letters are then `Bag`-ged, which counts the number of occurrences, and only lines where `max == 1` occurrences exist (i.e. no duplicate letters) are returned.

There seems to be some commentary on what constitutes a "word" for this problem. If you want to count hyphenated words as separate words, split on hyphens first by adding `.split("-")` to the beginning of the method chain (before `.words`).

To give you an idea of how the Raku code above is working, here's the core of the code *with* the `split` routine, but *without* the `if` conditional, and without the `max` conditional:

```
raku -ne '.split("-").words.map(*.comb(/ ^<upper> /)).Bag.put;' 

H(2) M A(2) T(2) E S F(3)
T(2) N E(2) H(2) O F(2) M A(2)
M S(2) T(2) N A(2) E H(2) F(2)
O(2) H(2) S(2) A(2) T(2) N
M H(2) A(2) S(3) F T(5)
S(2) F(3) A(2) H(2) T(2) M
T(3) H(2) S E F N A(2)
H(2) T S M N A(2) F(4) E
A E F H N T
E T F N H S A
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Predefined_character_classes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

The following perl script is overly verbose, and could be shortened considerably, but was written to demonstrate the algorithm clearly rather than cryptically succinct:

```
$ cat caps.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

MAIN: while(<>) {
  # skip lines without a capital letter
  next unless /[A-Z]/;

  # hash to hold the counts of the first letters of each word,
  # reset to empty for every input line
  my %letters = ();

  foreach my $w (split /[-\s]+/) {
    # ignore "words" not beginning with a letter
    next unless $w =~ m/^[[:alpha:]]/; 

    # get the first character of the word
    my $l = substr($w,0,1);

    # uncomment if you want upper- and lower-case to be treated
    # as the same letter:
    #$l = uc($l);

    $letters{$l}++;

    # If we've seen this letter before on this line, skip to the
    # next input line.
    next MAIN if $letters{$l} > 1;
  };

  # the input line has no first letters which appear more than once, so print it.
  print;
}
```

None of your sample input lines would print with the criteria you gave, so I added your two sample output lines to the input:

```
$ ./caps.pl input.txt 
FIFTY THOUSAND, NINE HUNDRED AND EIGHTEEN
FOURTEEN THOUSAND, SEVEN HUNDRED AND NINETY-EIGHT
```